# Combine multiple arrays in one array of hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have a hashes like this

```
name = ['Jhon Doe', 'Jane Doe' , 'David']
role = ['Admin', 'Accountant', 'Sales']
```

i want to make it look like this

```
data = [
      {name => 'Jhon Doe', role => 'Admin'},
      {name => 'Jane Doe', role => 'Accountan'},
      {name => 'David', role => 'Sales'}
]
```

is it posible to do something like this?

Comment: name and role are not valid hashes

Comment: they don't look like hashes at all :D

Comment: Haha sorry i'm a beginner, but can i merge these two look like data ?

Comment: Your input hashes are arrays, not hashes, and your desired output is not legal Ruby (unless `name` and `role` are defined and initialized local variables or methods in scope). Also, what does this have to do with Rails?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a rather simple solution:

```ruby
name.zip(role).map {|name, role| { name:, role: }}
#=> [
#     { name: 'Jhon Doe', role: 'Admin' },
#     { name: 'Jane Doe', role: 'Accountant' },
#     { name: 'David',    role: 'Sales' }
#   ]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve desired result using `map` and `with_index`:

```
name.map.with_index { |name_i, index| { name: name_i, role: role[index] } }
```

Answer (score 1):

here name and role should be an `array`, not `hash`

```
name = ['Jhon Doe', 'Jane Doe' , 'David']
role = ['Admin', 'Accountant', 'Sales']
```

you can use the below to generate the output hash

```
my_hash_array = []
name.size.times{|i| my_hash_array << {name: name[i], role: role[i]} }
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: You can replace `size.times` with `each_index`.